# Unable to upload media to server with php tmp folder error

Tags: php, wordpress, tmp

*I've seen similar questions but the solutions are workarounds or hacks that only for WordPress. this is a PHP issue and i want to solve it for all applications not just WordPress, **to the problem:***

The site media library (Wordpress) will not allow uploads. This is the error:

```
Missing a temporary folder.
```

So i investigated a bit: phpinfo(); says:

```
sys_temp_dir    no value
```

One would think that's the problem but then i read inside php.ini:

```
; Defaults to the system default (see sys_get_temp_dir)
```

So i printed sys_get_temp_dir(); and i get:

```
/tmp
```

I go check /tmp and it exists. Permissions are "777".

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by setting:

```
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
```

Despite it falling to system default when empty it seems like you REALLY need to have it there as well. AND Still no idea how it worked before or how it disappeared.